# javafx How to stage never have focus when shown

Tags: javafx, notifications

I am trying to imitiate windows notification  right bottom  popup rectangle by using stage. In order for it to always be shown when another **app** is open, i used `stage.setAlwaysOnTop(true);` property which is working. Problem is when the stage ( my notification) shows up it gets the focus from everything meaning users need to click the app they are on **again** to regain lost focus. Is there any way my stage  to never gets focus but is always shown in front of other apps?